# Get value from Pickerview when it is not user accessible

Tags: swift3, uipickerview

I am working on an app that uses a `UIPickerView` in the same way a slot machine would work. The user cannot spin it and it does not recognize user touches. The selection is randomized after a button pressed.

The question is, how can I get the data of the pickerview's row?

`pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)` does not work since the user does not really select anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerview/1614369-selectedrow) to get the selected row:

> ```
> func selectedRow(inComponent component: Int) -> Int
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> *component*   : A zero-indexed number identifying a component of the picker view.
>
> Return value
>
> A zero-indexed number identifying the selected row, or -1 if no row is selected.

Use it:

```
let row = picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
let item = pickerArray[row]
```

`picker` is the `UIPickerView` instance.
`pickerArray` is the data source array of the picker view.